# How to update UI using React render() on user interaction?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render() {
  const skills = App.skills.map((label, index) => {
       const value = User.SKILLS[index];
       const stateSkills = new Set(this.state.skills);
       console.log("VALUE", value);
       console.log('State skills', stateSkills);
       const checked = stateSkills.has(value);
       return (
         <Skills
           key={value}
           value={value}
           label={label}
           checked={checked}
           addSkills={this.addSkills.bind(this)}
           removeSkills={this.removeSkills.bind(this)}
        />
    );
});
```

I set this.state.skills using this.setState after requesting data from an endpoint. Then I was trying to update the checkbox using stateSkills.has(value). Even though that evaluates to true, the checkbox is not ticked. Logging stateSkills here does show the right data fetched from the endpoint.

```
import React from 'react';
import {CellBody, CellHeader, Checkbox, FormCell} from 'react-weui';


const Skills = ({label, value, checked, addSkills, removeSkills}) => {
  const toggle = checked ? removeSkills : addSkills;

  return (
    <FormCell
      checkbox
       key={value}
    >
    <CellHeader>
      <Checkbox
        name={value}
        value={value}
        defaultChecked={checked}
        onClick={() => toggle(value)}
    />
   </CellHeader>

  <CellBody>{label}</CellBody>
</FormCell>
 );
};

 Skills.propTypes = {
   label: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   value: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   checked: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
   addSkills: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
   removeSkills: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
 };

 export default Skills;
```

Comment: Your render method does not look right to me. What are you returning `skills`?  What is App.skills? is it a static property or is it a react state?

Comment: Skills is a component. App.skills is a static property.

Comment: Could you show us Skills component?

Comment: Added the component.

Comment: What determines whether `Checkbox` component is checked or not? is it the variable `checked` or `value`?

Comment: Initially, all checkboxes are empty. Thereafter, it is dependent on the value.

Answer (score 0):

When re-render in current component, props of Skills change, it re-render Skills but it didn't change checked value (maybe it's state), you should define in component Skills:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.checked !== this.props.checked) {
    // setState and it will re-render
  } 
}
```

Comment: Aren't changes to state or props trigger re-render of component? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Comment: @D-reaper, yes it does, but we have to see how the OP has written his `Skills` component. Since checked property is being used there

Comment: Edited @D-reaper
I think you should provide `Skills` in detail